# Modified .css doesn't get updated in browser

Tags: php, css, apache, caching

I modified a CSS file, but the change doesn't show up in the browser!
I'm using httpd and PHP 7.1 on Centos.

I tried:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, hard refresh and cache clear.
- Apache header "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate".
- PHP opcache is disabled.

I made sure:

- The file has been modified on the remote machine.
- I restarted httpd
- Firewalld is disabled

The only working solution is to reboot the remote machine, but that's completely unpractical.

**EDIT:** After running debug logging on the server, I found out that no request to the CSS file is actually received, so it probably comes from the client.

Any idea?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Does this happen on the production or in testing only?

Comment: @Koby Douek I tried Vivaldi (chromium based) and Chrome.

Comment: @KobyDouek I don't have a production environment for now for this project

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with 2 methods:

1. Disable cache in Chrome by clicking F12 and disabling cache in developer tools settings, under the "Network" tab:

   [image]

---

2. In your HTML page, link the CSS file with a version param you can change each time you modify your CSS:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mycss.css?ver=121" />`

Comment: @Mena12 If you've done these 2 things and your pages still show your "old" CSS, then your CSS is not really changed. Check the problem elsewhere - perhaps your apache server caches it so it does not even reach the browser?

Comment: How can I check apache's cache, if it has one? Opcache is disabled, and I don't know anything else that could do caching.

Comment: @Mena12 There's no CSS chaching on Apache that I am aware of too. This is why I suggest you double check if you actually changed the CSS the page is looking at, because the 2 steps in my answer are 100% to disable caching of any sort.

Comment: Are you using a CSS compiler? like compass? are you using SASS?

Comment: Yes, I doubled checked with vim on the remote machine.

Comment: I'm not using any compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Use             `ctrl + shift + R`  refresh the entire page

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
     CTRL + Shift + R
```

It overrides cache and reloads the page.

Comment: Didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If You talk about Chrome - open developer console and then ctrl + F5 ... Chrome start working strange and not always reload scripts and stylesheets when developer console is closed.

Comment: Then problem must be on server side. Don't You use some engine to minified CSS ? For example in Ruby on Rails all assets like CSS are joined and refreshed only when You ask for it.